# Github workflow for NodeJS CI

Tags: github, github-actions, github-for-windows

I am currently working on a simple web application that is open source (https://github.com/Abdullanz/ExpenseAnalyzer) and I am trying to learn how Github workflow works. Therefore, I decided to use NodeJS CI template provided from Github, however, it does not run, and I can't understand why. Can you please help me? Thank you

The error msg:
.github#L1
Process completed with exit code 1.

[The yml file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6YF1p.jpg)

Comment: Please give a [mre] **as text**.

Comment: `npm run` wont know to go into your `v1` folder, perhaps you prob need `working-directory: ./v1` in the action